# Accessing parent directive scope

Tags: angularjs

So, I am trying to have 2 directives (techincally 3) on one page, which looks like this:

```
<div kd-alert newsletter></div>
<div kd-alert cookie></div>
```

this is on the index page, so there are no controllers.
I have been playing around with isolating scopes with directives and I have found that even though within the link function, scopes are isolated, if your directives use controllers the templates can see both controllers and if both controllers have a property with the same name they can be overwritten by the other controller, which is a nightmare so I decided to create a parent directive with one controller that serves the other 2 directives.

The parent directive in this case is called **kd-alert** and looks like this:

```
.directive('kdAlert', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'AlertController',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

            // Have to use a watch because of issues with other directives
            scope.$watch(function () {

                // Watch the dismiss
                return controller.dismiss;

                // If the value changes
            }, function (dismiss) {

                // If our value is false
                if (dismiss === false || dismiss === 'false') {

                    // Remove the class from the element
                    element.removeClass('ng-hide');

                    // Else, if the value is true (or anything else)
                } else {

                    // Add the class to the element
                    element.addClass('ng-hide');
                }
            });

            // Get our buttons
            var buttons = element.find('button');

            // Binds our close button
            scope.bindCloseButton = function (cookieName) {

                // If we have a button
                for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {

                    // Get our current button
                    var button = angular.element(buttons[i]);

                    // If our button is the close button
                    if (button.hasClass('close')) {

                        // If the button is clicked
                        button.on('click', function (e) {

                            console.log('clicked');

                            // Prevent any default actions
                            e.preventDefault();

                            // dismiss the alert
                            controller.dismissAlert(cookieName);

                            // Remove our element
                            element.remove();
                        });
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    };
})
```

The controller handles methods for both child directives but is still pretty thin. It looks like this:

```
.controller('AlertController', ['$cookies', 'SubscriberService', 'toastr', function ($cookies, subscriverService, toastr) {
    var self = this;

    // Set our dismiss to false
    self.dismiss = false;

    // Set the flag
    self.getDismissValue = function (cookieName) {

        // Set our cookie
        self.dismiss = $cookies[cookieName] || false;
    };

    // Set the flag
    self.dismissAlert = function (cookieName) {

        // Set our cookie
        self.dismiss = $cookies[cookieName] = true;
    };

    // Saves our email address
    self.subscribe = function (email, cookieName) {

        // Subscribe
        subscriverService.subscribe(email).success(function () {

            // If we succeed, display a message
            toastr.success('You will now recieve occasional newsletters.');

            // Dismiss the alert
            self.dismissAlert(cookieName);
        });
    };
}])
```

Now I have a **cookie** directive which works fine...

```
.directive('cookie', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^kdAlert',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/directives/cookie.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

            console.log(scope);

            // Get our cookie name
            var cookieName = 'cookieAlert';

            // Get our dismiss value
            controller.getDismissValue(cookieName);

            // Bind our close button
            scope.bindCloseButton(cookieName);
        }
    };
})
```

When I refresh my page I can clearly see the scope with the bindCloseButton method within that scope. So far so good.
The problem is with the **newsletter** directive, it looks like this:

```
.directive('newsletter', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^kdAlert',
        templateUrl: '/assets/tpl/directives/newsletter.html',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, controller) {

            console.log(scope);

            // Get our cookie name
            var cookieName = 'newsletterAlert';

            // Get our dismiss value
            controller.getDismissValue(cookieName);

            // Bind our close button
            scope.bindCloseButton(cookieName);

            // Saves our email address
            scope.subscribe = function (valid) {

                // If we are not valid
                if (!valid) {

                    // Return from the function
                    return;
                }

                // Subscribe
                controller.subscribe(scope.email, cookieName);
            };
        }
    };
})
```

Again, if I refresh the page I can clearly see the **bindCloseButton** method within that scope, but for some reason I get this error:

> > scope.bindCloseButton is not a function

And that appears on the line within the **newsletter** directive.
If I remove the cookie directive off the page, I still get the error.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use controller.bindCloseButton instead of scope.bindCloseButton .

This is happening because of the isolation of scope. you are doing in this approach and that's why you are losing scopes here.

Comment: I thought someone might say that. I like keeping DOM functions out of controllers, but if there is no other way .... :(

Comment: Yes that's right..
But i don't know what you are trying to do.
But what i say in you code that's wrong implementation.